# Colgroup in ffox/chrome

Tags: html, css

I am testing the `<colgroup>` tag on a 5 columns table, with a style attribute.

I can't seem to make it work on firefox 3.6/chrome 5 tho, and this is when I started searching  for the reference on w3c.
It seemed like my code was perfectly fine, but looking at the [w3c editor](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_colgroup_test) I noticed not even that was working. Only IE8 seems to work correctly, opera 10.51 ignores the style tag but  applies the align tag correctly, while ffox and chrome seems to ignore colgroup completely.

So what am I (and w3c) doing wrong? Was colgroup deprecated and I missed it?

Comment: The w3c editor? Err. W3Schools is a crappy tutorial site. It is **not** the W3C.

Comment: Good point, it's not w3c, however I checked the specifications for the colgroup tag, and the style attribute is allowed, yet its content is ignored. It may be a crappy tutorial site, but I cannot find what's wrong on that specific link I posted, and my question is about what's wrong there (which is the same problem I'm experiencing with my own code)

Comment: You've already got two answers which explain why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table cells are not descendants of the columns they are in (hierarchical data structures don't represent 2 dimensional data very well).

Hixie explains in detail: http://ln.hixie.ch/?count=1&start=1070385285

Comment: That makes colgroups nearly useless, but I see why it is necessary, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The CSS 2.1 Standard only allows a very small selection of properties to apply to cells in columns, because the cells are not real descendants of columns.

Some browsers such als Firefox adhere to these standards, while others allow more properties to take effect.

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#columns

If you want to apply other properties such as text-align you should give all cells in the column the same class and apply the style to that class.

Comment: Giving every cell in a column the same class defeats the purpose of using `colgroup`s and `col`s in the first place. They might as well remove `colgroup` and `col` from the specification entirely, because by that logic, nothing about styling a column - an object never rendered in the first place - should ever affect a cell.

Answer (score 1):

You can also match a specic colum by using the adjacent sibling selectors in css, like:

```
td + td + td{... some style ....}
```